# A film about unreal world with monsters who kill people who is living in a hidden place

Tags: story-identification, movie

It is not *Inception*.

I have seen this film but I do not know its name or if it is a known movie, I will just tell you what I remember and if you could help me to find this film.

There was a man who thought he would win a contract because of his design work, but actually, he was being kidnapped to an unreal world where you can jump between places. It is like a dream world, and those people are living inside it. There are monsters with long black legs inside this world who are attracted to humans and try to kill them. People are fighting those monsters and trying to destroy them. The people are living in a hidden place with an entrance inside a bus.

It appears that the man was kidnapped to design a layer or a city in that world. He wakes up to find that this is not real and tries to kill the man or team responsible for doing this. At the end of the film that man builds his own city in that world.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  It was live-action?

Comment: Thanks @DavidW, I saw that in a friend's house who is not reachable anymore, so I do not know what service was used to show the film. 
Yes it was live-action with computer-generated effects.

Comment: As soon as someone says "this isn't *Inception*", my first thought is "then it must either be *Coma* or *Doctor Strange*"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is [*Coma*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coma_(2020_film)) (AKA *Koma*) from 2020.

> "Coma" follows the story of a talented architect who, after a
> mysterious accident, awakens in a dystopian world. This reality is a
> labyrinthine space composed of the memories, dreams, and subconscious
> thoughts of those in comas. In this surreal and fragmented landscape,
> physical laws are inconsistent, and cities and technologies from
> various eras coexist. The architect learns he can shape reality with
> his thoughts but struggles to distinguish between the world of 'Coma'
> and the real world. As he navigates this perplexing realm, he must
> confront the implications of his newfound abilities while uncovering
> the truth behind the coma world's existence.

Comment: This looks like its a remake of this kids show: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D48hrkSEEGQ